# IntentService from within a class that extends TimerTask

Tags: java, android

I need to call a class that extends an IntentService from within a class that extends TimerTask. I am struggling to figure out how context works when using Intent in this manner.

Running from MainActivity I set up my timer and run the timer() class which extends TimerTask.

```java
Timer poll_timer = new Timer();
poll_timer.schedule(new timer(),0, 1000);
```

This code is part of the timer() class but I dont know how to correctly call use the Intent or pass the MainActivity context to the timer() class.
This is how I would call it from my MainActivity

```java
Intent gps = new Intent(this, gps.class);
startService(gps);
```

Any help on this one would be much appreciated as I am fairly new to Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, pass context object to TimerTask class and use it their to invoke startService.

In Activity code,

```
 Timer poll_timer = new Timer();
 poll_timer.schedule(new Timertesttask(MainActivity.this),0, 1000);
```

TimerTask code,

```
public class Timertesttask extends TimerTask {
    Context ctxObject = null;
    public Timertesttask(Context ctx) {
        ctxObject = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent gpsintent = new Intent(ctxObject, Gps.class);
        ctxObject.startService(gpsintent);
    }
}
```

your Intent Service class,

```
public class Gps extends IntentService {


    public Gps() {
        super("Gps");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Testing","Testing");
    }
}
```

Put entry of IntentService in AndroidManifest

```
<service android:name=".Gps" />
```